# Get custom post type category and list all posts with the same category

Tags: php, wordpress

**The problem I have is as follows:**

- I have custom post type named 'X'.
- It has few categories named 'Category_1', 'Category_2', 'Category_3' 
  etc.
- By the logic of my website, one post can only have one category or no category at all.

On page `single-x.php` (single-posttypename.php) I want to check, if post has a category at all, if it has, I want to get all other posts with the same category, and provide them as a sub-navigation. If post does not have a category just do nothing.

```
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="link-to-post1">post1</a></li>
  <li><a href="link-to-post2">post2</a></li>
  ...
</ul>
```

For the current post, I want to add class active so it would act as a navigation.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a check like this

```
$x= $_POST['x'];
if(isset($x) && $x!='')
{
 $customise_category = $x; 
}

else
       {
       $customise_category = '';
       }
```

you can use this `$customise_category` where it is needed.